# Hibernate, c3p0, and Mysql, spring

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, c3p0

Many related issues are there at stack overflow but still i am putting this because still i haven't clear solution and exact reason for my problem.
I hope here i get complete solution of my problem and help full for All

I am using c3p0, MySQL, hibernate(J PA) and spring in my application.
Listing of main jar files i am using in my application is:

```
c3p0-0.9.2.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar
hibernate-entity manager.jar
hibernate-tools.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hibernate3.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
```

c3p0 settings in my persistent.XML is like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
```

Here that somewhere i read that hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period must
not be higher of the  hibernate.c3p0.timeout. In my case both are equal.

**Is i need to change anything ?
how can i solve this problem ?**

Server works fine for some hours(may be till 8 hours not exactly) and gives following error. error log is:

```
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
    Communications link failure
    The last packet successfully received from the server was 35,019,246 milliseconds
     ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at             sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at      sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at         com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
        at         com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery
    (NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server.
    Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2502)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2952)
        ... 52 more
    ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3302)
        ... 50 more
```

**Here I am showing the snapshot of my persistent.xml:-**

```
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***************"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.x.xx:3306/projectname?autoReconnect=true"/>
      <!--Connection Pooling c3p0 configuration-->
      <!--Minimum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 1-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
      <!--Maximum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 100-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
      <!--When an idle connection is removed from the pool (in second). Hibernate default: 0, never expire.-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
      <!--Number of prepared statements will be cached. Increase performance. Hibernate default: 0 , caching is disable.-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
      <!--idle time in seconds before a connection is automatically validated. Hibernate default: 0-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
    </properties>
```

**I use singleton object of connection class in my application.**

```
public static void createConnection() 
{
    if (em != null) 
       {
            Connection.em.clear();
        }
        if (em == null) {
            new Connection();
        }
```

**Thanks in advance. Hope i will get my solution.**

**--Om--**

Answer (score 2):

A singleton Connection object is a bad idea (at least it is in any concurrent, multi-client application). It is certainly inconsistent with a Connection pool, the philosophy of which is that Connections should be acquired from the pool when they are needed and returned to the pool [by calling close()] as soon as a unit of work is done.

Right now, your singleton Connection will timeout, and there is nothing c3p0 can do about it. Connection pools manage and test Connections when they are checked into the pool. When they are checked out, the pool tries to stay out of the way and not interfere with the client.

==> All of that said, it's unclear what your "Connection" class is here. It looks like it is not a java.sql.Connection after all, because you have a static field called "em" in Connection. So it is hard to interpret what's going on.

Broadly, you want a single c3p0 DataSource, and to acquire Connections as-needed and to close() them as promptly as possible.

To prevent Connection timeouts like you are seeing, the best approach a Connection testing regime. The easiest approach would be to set...

```
hibernate.c3p0.validate=true
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
```

Once you have that working, you can enhance the performance a bit by using testConnectionOnCheckin and idleConnectionTestPeriod (or hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period). See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

It makes no sense to have your idleConnectionTestPeriod (hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period) and maxIdleTime (hibernate.c3p0.timeout) be the same. Idle connections will never be tested; they'll expire before they get the chance. idleConnectionTestPeriod (hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period), if you set it at all, should be much shorter than maxIdleTime (hibernate.c3p0.timeout).

Good luck!

Comment: **Thanks a lot Steve**

My Connection class snapshot is like that

    public class Connection {
    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    public static EntityManager em;
    static EntityTransaction t;
    public Connection() {
    emf =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RollerSkattePU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

i altered my code. 
will share soon the that is my problem solved.?

Answer (score 1):

As this is the first hit in Google I'll share what brought me the solution to this problem showing up on our production servers: http://drglennn.blogspot.nl/2009/05/javasqlsqlexception-communication-link.html

What made this a nasty bug is that the application will work by ommitting:

```
 <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

in your persistence-unit config but it will not use the C3P0 Connection Pool and will therefore generate connection failures.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

That exception means Database isn't reachable.

Since you are able to connect to Database I guess issue might be

1) DB server is down at that time

2) DB server has run out of connections.

Try connecting to Database using some other tool, MySQL Workbench or from console, at the time you get this exception

Answer (score 0):

You should rater configure you a datasource. Otherwise there is much trouble with the interaction of spring an c3o0.

```
<bean id="dataSource_core" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${hibernate.connection.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${hibernate.connection.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${hibernate.connection.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${hibernate.connection.maxStmts}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${hibernate.connection.testCo}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${hibernate.connection.testCo}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${hibernate.connection.testSQL}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${hibernate.connection.testPeriod}" />
</bean>
```